# The write command is python is not working

Tags: python

I wrote something like this:

```
lines = [name]
with open('user/username.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(lines)
```

and it put nothing in the "user" folder.

Comment: ``user/username.txt`` is a relative path. Did you check for the result relative to the script or relative to the working directory?

Comment: `lines` is a list; `f.write` expects a `str`, and will not (like `print`) implicitly call `str` on its argument.

Comment: Either you missed the exception `f.write` raises in this case, or this is not equivalent to the code you are actually running (which is subject to the issue raised by MisterMiyagi).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to iterate over the list. Here's an example.

```
lines = ["John Smith", "Jane Doe"]
with open('user/username.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
      # If the strings don't contain end of line you might want to insert one like here
      f.write(line + "\n")
```